# Google Sheets Script getLastRow() - How to get submission values, for each NEW ITEM (rows)?

Tags: function, email, google-apps-script, datatable, range

Could someone guide me, I have tried many different ways but can't find out the problems.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>


<body>

  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
<body style="font-family:roboto,light,300;font-size:14px;font-style:normal;">

<div >
  <p> 
Hi there,<br/><br/>
The following case requires to be process.<br/>Please have a look and update the spreadsheet, click here to open: <br/>
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hPfBxMpXABG09cPOvzAQu0SDZLf-TSUTvv4_02BA8HE/edit#gid=0  <br/> 
  </p> 

</div>

</body>


<head>
  <style>
  table {width:75%;}
  table, th, td 
  {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  }
  th, td 
  {
  padding: 14px;
  text-align: left;
  }

  #t01 tr:nth-child(even) 
  {
  background-color: #eee;
  }
  #t01 tr:nth-child(odd) 
  {
 background-color: #fff;
  }
  #t01 th 
  {
  background-color: #3e8cbd;
  color: white;
  }
  </style>
</head>
<body>

<table id="t01">
 <tr>
    <th width="100" scope="col" >Status</th>
    <th scope="col"  >Language</th>
    <th scope="col"  >P/R</th>
    <th scope="col"  >DJID F-Code</th>
    <th scope="col"  >Deadline</th>
  </tr>

  <tr> 
    <td><?= subVals[0][1] ?></td>
    <td><?= subVals[0][5] ?></td>
     <td><?= subVals[0][6] ?></td>
    <td><?= subVals[0][7] ?></td> 
    <td><?= deadline ?></td>
  </tr>
</table>  

</body>

<body>
  <br/>

  <head>
  <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body style="font-family:roboto,light,300;font-size:14px;font-style:normal;">

  <div >
<p> Should you have any questions or doubts please reach out to us: xxxxxx@gmail.com <br/> <br/>  Best Regards, </p> 
  </div>
</body>


</html>
```

1. I'd like to sendEmail to the different receivers with all NEW ITEM (rows) that are submitted in google sheet.
   So far when I run the script, only 1 row will be sent, row3. What part am I missing for "all rows with data" to be sent?

[image]

2. Add Email to Distribution List from "Backstage" tab with a list of recipience email, is running without an error but it won't send an email the list of people . I supposed something is missing here?

[image]

```js
[![enter image description here][3]][3]




function sendEmail() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(),
      sheet = ss.getSheetByName('ESCALATION');                          //Code running off "ESCALATION" tab
    
    var row = 3; 
      subVals = sheet.getRange(row, 1, 1, 22).getValues(),              

      deadline = sheet.getRange(3, 13).getDisplayValue(),             //Gets display value of deadline date to pass to html file due to time/date formatting
      subject = "Escalations Report";                                 //Create subject variable

  var template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Email Table');   //Create template of html file
  
  template.subVals = subVals;                                         //Send subVals variables to template so can reference in html using scriplets
  template.deadline = deadline;                                        //Send deadline variable to template so can reference in html using scriplets
  
  var html = template.evaluate().getContent();                        //Evalutate and create html output
  
  var sendto = "xxxxxx@gmail.com";                                    //Test send Email only to myself 
 

// Add Email to Distribution List    > is not working!!???
      var BACKsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Backstage");   // "Backstage" tab with a list of recipience email
      var columnValues = BACKsheet.getRange(1, 10, BACKsheet.getLastRow()).getValues();    //1st is header row 
   
  
 GmailApp.sendEmail(sendto, subject, '', {htmlBody:html});   //send email with recipients from subVals and options set htmlBody to html variable we created 
}
```

[image]

Comment: Your code contains the lines:  `   var row = 3;  subVals = sheet.getRange(row, 1, 1, 22).getValues()` - so you are retrieving only the values from this row. If you are also interested in the other rows you need to to loop through them accordingly - showing your spreadsheet (or a screenshot of it) and a more detiled description of what you are achieving to do would be helpful.

Comment: In addition to the comment above, more specifically `sheet.getRange(row, 1, 1, 22).getValues()` means you are asking to collect values starting from row 3 and column 1 for a total of 1 rows and 22 columns. Your email distribution list has the right idea with the `.getLastRow()` but you will need to adjust a little. Onto your distribution list building: there is nothing there. All you do is get an array of column 1 values. Recipients have to be a comma separated string and not an array.

Comment: @ziganotschka I added a screenshot of my spreadsheet. Could you have a look at it and guide me on this, please.  Much appreciated!

Comment: I did try different ways (1 and 2 ) but none worked. For example instead of ` var row = 3; subVals = sheet.getRange(row, 1, 1, 22).getValues()` :    

1.     
//lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
//subVals = sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow(), 1, 1 ,22).getValues();   //  TEST last ROW that has data in it    
2.     
//  subVals = sheet.getRange(lastRow -1 , 1, 1 ,22).getValues();         // TEST last ROW that has data in it  //lastRow-1

Comment: When you say `I'd like to sendEmail to the different receivers with all NEW ITEM (rows) that are submitted in google sheet` what do you mean by submitted.  Are you talking about a form submission?

Comment: How about reorganizing your html so that there is one head and one body.  Put the head before the body like a standard html setup.

Comment: @Cooper, send Email to a list of recipients, taking the email addresses from a  "Backstage tab" , Col K.

Comment: @Cooper, oh I am not sure how to that... believe it or not it took me ages to figure my current **hmtl** out :(

Comment: BTW on backstage column K is 11 not 10

Comment: @Cooper changed to 11 (Col K), anyway the [var] is still not working for "Email to Distribution List".  "cry"

Comment: @Cooper, Email send out to different recipients worked. Thanks a lot!!! 
But my main issue is still not solved, item **1 .** I'd like to `sendEmail`  to the different receivers with all NEW ITEM (rows) that are submitted in google sheet. So far when I run the script, only 1 row will be sent, row3. What part am I missing for "all rows with data" to be sent? Could you advise me?

Comment: @ziganotschka, can you advise me with my item **1.** in order **to send any item in a row with data**, _not only row3_, as it is for the moment? 
`const subVals = sheet.getRange(3, 1, 1, 22).getValues(); `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified your html and provide some fake data of mine and sent two emails.  I also modified the recipient portion of the code it needed to be flattened and joined with a comma.

The gs:

```
function sendEmail() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const esh = ss.getSheetByName('ESCALATION');
  const subVals = esh.getRange(3, 1, 1, 22).getValues();
  const deadline = esh.getRange(3, 13).getDisplayValue();
  const subject = "Escalations Report";
  let template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('ah1');
  template.subVals = subVals;
  template.deadline = deadline;
  let html = template.evaluate().getContent();
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html),'Test')
  let bsh = ss.getSheetByName("Backstage");
  let recipient = bsh.getRange(1, 11, bsh.getLastRow()).getValues().flat().join(',');
  GmailApp.sendEmail(recipient,subject, '', { htmlBody: html });
}
```

The html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
      <style>
  table {width:75%;}
  table, th, td {border: 1px solid black;border-collapse: collapse;}
  th, td {padding: 14px;text-align: left;}
  #t01 tr:nth-child(even) {background-color: #eee;}
  #t01 tr:nth-child(odd) {background-color: #fff;}
  #t01 th {background-color: #3e8cbd;color: white;}
  </style>
  </head>
<body style="font-family:roboto,light,300;font-size:14px;font-style:normal;">
<div >
  <p> Hi there,<br/><br/>The following case requires to be process.<br/>Please have a look and update the spreadsheet, click 
<a href="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hPfBxMpXABG09cPOvzAQu0SDZLf-TSUTvv4_02BA8HE/edit#gid=0">here</a> to open: <br/> 
  </p> 
</div>
<table id="t01">
 <tr><th width="100" scope="col" >Status</th><th scope="col"  >Language</th><th scope="col"  >P/R</th><th scope="col"  >DJID F-Code</th><th scope="col"  >Deadline</th>
  </tr>
  <tr> <td><?= subVals[0][1] ?></td><td><?= subVals[0][5] ?></td><td><?= subVals[0][6] ?></td><td><?= subVals[0][7] ?></td><td><?= deadline ?></td></tr>
</table>  
  <br/>
   <div >
<p> Should you have any questions or doubts please reach out to us: xxxxxx@gmail.com <br/> <br/>  Best Regards, </p> 
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The email:

[image]

The code for three lines:
GS:

```
function sendEmail() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const esh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  const bsh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet2");
  const recipient = bsh.getRange(1, 11, bsh.getLastRow()).getValues().flat().join(',');
  const vs = esh.getRange(3, 1, 3, 22).getValues();
  const subject = "Escalations Report";
  vs.forEach(r => {
    let template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('ah1');
    template.subVals = r;
    let html = template.evaluate().getContent();
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html), 'Test');
    let end = "is near";
    GmailApp.sendEmail(recipient, subject, '', { htmlBody: html });
  });
}
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
      <style>
  table {width:75%;}
  table, th, td {border: 1px solid black;border-collapse: collapse;}
  th, td {padding: 14px;text-align: left;}
  #t01 tr:nth-child(even) {background-color: #eee;}
  #t01 tr:nth-child(odd) {background-color: #fff;}
  #t01 th {background-color: #3e8cbd;color: white;}
  </style>
  </head>
<body style="font-family:roboto,light,300;font-size:14px;font-style:normal;">
<div >
  <p> Hi there,<br/><br/>The following case requires to be process.<br/>Please have a look and update the spreadsheet, click 
<a href="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hPfBxMpXABG09cPOvzAQu0SDZLf-TSUTvv4_02BA8HE/edit#gid=0">here</a> to open: <br/> 
  </p> 
</div>
<table id="t01">
 <tr><th width="100" scope="col" >Status</th><th scope="col"  >Language</th><th scope="col"  >P/R</th><th scope="col"  >DJID F-Code</th><th scope="col"  >Deadline</th>
  </tr>
  <tr> <td><?= subVals[1] ?></td><td><?= subVals[5] ?></td><td><?= subVals[6] ?></td><td><?= subVals[7] ?></td><td><?= subVals[12] ?></td></tr>
</table>  
  <br/>
   <div >
<p> Should you have any questions or doubts please reach out to us: xxxxxx@gmail.com <br/> <br/>  Best Regards, </p> 
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Note: Both the gs and the html have changed

Comment: much appreciated your help. I have added 2 screenshots: The Escalation tab + Backstage tab.